# Kubernetes UI: error in kubectl proxy

Tags: linux, docker, kubernetes

I am trying to run kubernetes User Interface. I am getting error

```
[root@ts_kubernetes_setup gcp-live-k8s-visualizer]# kubectl proxy
Error in configuration: context was not found for specified context: cluster51
```

I followed this http://kubecloud.io/guide-setting-up-visualizer-for-kubernetes/

Then I tried to delete this cluster using

```
kubectl config delete-cluster my-cluster
kubectl config delete-context my-cluster-context
kubectl config unset users.my-cluster-admin
```

After performing the last step when I am trying to run `kubectl proxy` I am getting the error. Suggest a clean way to get UI.

Comment: Also I want to try this out https://github.com/google/cluster-insight

Comment: same is happening for 
`[root@ts_kubernetes_setup ~]# kubectl create -f discover.yaml -n kube-system
Error in configuration: context was not found for specified context: cluster51`

Answer (score 4):

when you did `kubectl config delete-context cluster51`, this deleted the context from your `~/.kube/config`. Hence the error:

```
Error in configuration: context was not found for specified context: cluster51
```

you can view the contents of the `~/.kube/config` file, or use the `kubectl config view` command to help troubleshoot this error.

Seems there is something (`config set-credentials`?) missing in these steps:

```
$ kubectl config set-cluster cluster51 --server=http://192.168.1.51:8080
$ kubectl config set-context cluster51 --cluster=cluster51
$ kubectl config use-context cluster51
```

If you're not running a rpi cluster and just want to play with kubernetes visualizer, may I suggest to use [kubernetes/minikube](http://github.com/kubernetes/minikube) instead?

Comment: I have to setup an environment to configure my spring boot application on kubernetes. So for that, I have already created docker image of that in the local registry. I also did `kubeadm reset`, but the problem persists.

Comment: that sentence, albeit long, does not answer any of the questions I asked about your setup - try again?

Answer (score 1):

It's might help for a beginner who stuck here and getting below message in kubenetes CLR.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

`kubectl config delete-cluster my-cluster` doesn't delete your cluster, it only removes the entry from your `kubectl` configuration. The error you are getting suggests that you need to configure kubectl correctly in order to use it with your cluster. I suggest you read the [kubectl documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/kubectl/kubectl_config/).